# Django ORM: group records by a field and then get the records with max field value in each group

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm

I have a model like this:

```
Class Foo(model.Models):
    date = models.DateField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    volume = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to get a list of all objects with the most price in each day! something like this:

```
{
   2017-01-01: {"date": 2017-01-01, "price": 1000, "volume": 210},
   2017-01-02: {"date": 2017-01-02, "price": 1032, "volumne": 242},
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Can I do this with one query? The database is relatively large and performing a loop on dates is not going to work.

Comment: I could show you a conventional query easily enough, but you'd have to figure out how to get that to work in your django environment. If that's what you want, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this to get the max price for a particular date

```
from django.db.models import Max

Foo.objects.values('date').annotate(max_price=Max('price'))
```

Edit: If you want to get the entire object which has the max price for a particular date, you can achieve that through `OuterRef` and `Subquery`, supported in Django 1.11

```
from django.db.models import Max, Subquery, OuterRef

subquery = Foo.objects.filter(date=OuterRef('date')).order_by('-price')
queryset = Foo.objects.filter(price=Subquery(subquery.values('price')[:1]))
```

This will create a subquery to get the object with the max price value for a given date, and then filter the main queryset by this subquery. You can read more about Subquery at [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions).

Comment: this returns the max price only. I want the object that has the max price! (I want its volume too)